# CURL and PHP session based authentication

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I have an application on `https://app.example.com`. The application requires users to login; if they are *not* logged in they are redirected to `https://app.example.com/login.php` when attempting to access any URL on this domain.

When the user has logged in successfully the application uses native PHP sessions to maintain the login state.

We have a separate application on `https://db.example.com`. This has been built with CakePHP 3. It is configured so that a user will be unable to access any URL on this domain unless they have logged in through `https://app.example.com` first. This was done by configuring the `session.cookie_domain` to `.example.com` and then setting the cookie used for sessions to `PHPSESSID`:

```
// config/app.php on db.example.com
'Session' => [
    'defaults' => 'php',
    'cookie' => 'PHPSESSID',
    'timeout' => '0',
    'ini' => [
        'session.cookie_domain' => '.example.com',
        'session.cookie_httponly' => 'off'
    ]
];
```

There is a script included from `app.example.com` on `db.example.com` which runs on every request. This - combined with the ability to read the session cookie - means we are checking the user is logged in before they can access anything on `db.example.com`; they get redirected to `app.example.com/login.php` if not.

**Up to this point everything works fine**.

The problem is that I'm trying to make a CURL request (using Cake's in-built functionality for this: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/httpclient.html) in part of my application on `db.example.com` to another URL also on `db.example.com` but for response is a 302 redirect to `https://app.example.com/login.php`.

The request is made from `https://db.example.com/foo` to `https://db.example.com/bar` - which also requires an `id` parameter in the POST data - like this:

```
// Request made by /foo:
public function foo()
{
    $this->autoRender = false;

    $http = new Client();

    $response = $http->post('https://db.example.com/bar', [
        'id' => '12345'
    ]);

    debug($response);
}
```

The output from the above is a HTTP 302 with the location set to the login page on `app.example.com`:

```
object(Cake\Http\Client\Response) {
    [protected] code => (int) 302
    [protected] cookies => null
    [protected] reasonPhrase => 'Found'

// ...

'Set-Cookie' => [
    (int) 0 => 'PHPSESSID=g9aeqt2acol6av03rqul2puo20; path=/; domain=.example.com; secure'
    ],
'Location' => [
    (int) 0 => 'https://app.example.com/login.php'
    ], 

}
```

I have read [Keeping session alive with Curl and PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13020404/keeping-session-alive-with-curl-and-php) but can't see what else to configure to solve this?

I also don't understand the `cookies => null` part of the debug information, when `Set-Cookie` has the correct session/cookie/domain details.

Environment details:

- Both `app.example.com` and `db.example.com` are on the same server.
- Both use PHP 7.0.33
- `db.example.com` uses CakePHP 3.5.13 as a framework; but `app.example.com` uses vanilla PHP (no framework).
- Web server is Apache 2 / CentOS.

Comment: I don’t see you handling the session cookie anywhere in your code that makes the cURL request. Cookies received with any response will be stored _“in the originating instance of Http\Client”_ (quote docs) - but since you are starting with `$http = new Client();` here, I don’t think that should contain _any_ cookies at that point.

Comment: @misorude That's an interesting point although I don't understand what to do to change/fix it. My understanding is that because I've configured the "shared session" and `PHPSESSID` between the 2 sub-domains it should work. Things work fine in the browser but I accept it will be different here because it's the server (not the browser)  making the request?

Comment: The question you linked to already explains what would need to be done using native cURL - CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR/CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE would need to be set. Check https://stackoverflow.com/q/45406915/10283047 for how this is done using guzzle. (Not sure if that is what CakePHP uses, or if that has its own implementation of an HTTP client?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTTP client will not auto-populate itself with cookies from the application it's running in, or any other application state for that matter, and as mentioned by @misorude in the comments, your code doesn't set any cookies to the client, hence it won't send any.

You'll have to set the required session cookie yourself, for example like this for a single request:

```
$data = [
    'id' => '12345'
];
$config = [
    'cookies' => [
        //'PHPSESSID' => $this->request->getSession()->id() // before CakePHP 3.6
        'PHPSESSID' => $this->getRequest()->getSession()->id()
    ]
];
$response = $http->post('https://db.example.com/bar', $data, $config);
```

The supposed `cookies` property on the response object being empty is a debug display "problem", there is no custom debug output for that class, hence PHP defaults are being used, which will include protected properties like `$cookies`, which however is not being populated until you're invoking the proper methods for reading cookies, that is `getCookies()`, `getCookie()`, `getCookieData()`, or `getCookieCollection()`.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Http Client > Setting and Managing Cookies](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/httpclient.html#setting-and-managing-cookies)**
- **[Cookbook > Http Client > Accessing Cookie Data](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/httpclient.html#accessing-cookie-data)**

Comment: `Call to undefined method App\Controller\FooController::getRequest()`. If I populate `$config['cookies']['PHPSESSID']` with `$this->request->cookies['PHPSESSID']` (or hardcode the string in) it's still giving a 302 and the same issue.

Comment: @Andy `getRequest()` is only available as of CakePHP 3.6, I've updated the example. I don't really have any further suggestions on your issue, as the shown example works as is, you'll have to do some debugging to check what's wrong, use a network sniffer to check that the request is being issued correctly, and/or check what exactly the request looks like that hits your vanilla PHP application, make sure that the requested session is valid, that there aren't any other requirements (like referer/ip/etc checks)...

Comment: I'm marking this as the correct answer as what @ndm has written is correct. I've found that the error I'm getting is due to a script on our vanilla PHP application (`app.example.com`) as opposed to the way the session cookie is being passed. The information in this answer is still required however.